# What does Class<? extends ParentClass> mean?

Tags: java

I found a method like the one below.

```
public void simpleTest(Class <? extends ParentClass> myClass){

}
```

I didn't understand the expression : `Class <? extends ParentClass> myClass` here.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Would you like to elaborate ?

Comment: You mean you don't understand the wildcard "?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Class <? extends ParentClass> myClass` is a [method argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) whose type is a [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) that is [parameterized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) to ensure that what's passed is a Class that represents some type that is a [subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) of ParentClass.

i.e. given:

```
class ParentParentClass {}
class ParentClass extends ParentParentClass {}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {}
class ChildChildClass extends ChildClass {}

public void simpleTest(Class <? extends ParentClass> myClass) {}
```

These are valid:

```
simpleTest(ParentClass.class);
simpleTest(ChildClass.class);
simpleTest(ChildChildClass.class);
```

These aren't valid because the argument doesn't "fit" inside the required type:

```
simpleTest(ParentParentClass.class);
simpleTest(String.class);
simpleTest(Date.class);
simpleTest(Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of `java.lang.Class<T>`:

> T - the type of the class modeled by this Class object. For example, the type of String.class is `Class<String>`. Use `Class<?>` if the class being modeled is unknown.

Now replace String with your class: it's a [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) of a type which is a ParentClass or a subclass of ParentClass.

Answer (score 0):

Class  myClass - means that myClass should be a a sub type of ParentClass.

```
class MyClass extends ParentClass {
}

simpleTest(ParentClass.class); // this is ok
simpleTest(MyClass.class); // this is ok

class SomeOtherClass {
}
simpleTest(SomeOtherClass.class); // will result in compiler error
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic method taking a parametrized class.

It might be helpful to first consider a simpler generics example: `List<? extends ParentClass>` means it's a List that only takes objects that fulfill the is-a relationship with ParentClass. I.e. the parameter of the List implementation is-a ParentClass, but the type of the whole thing `List<? extends ParentClass>` is List.

In your example, just substitute "Class" instead of "List". `myClass` is a Class, i.e. you can call the method with something like "MyClassName.class". Further, the parameter of the Class of my Class is-a ParentClass. This basically means that you can only pass the Class of ParentClass or its subclasses to the method.

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html